# Using Chef Environments with Berkshelf

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

For my current project, I have an "Environment Cookbook" that has a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── Berksfile
├── Vagrantfile
├── environments
│   └── development.rb
├── metadata.rb
└── recipes
    └── default.rb
```

In my `Vagrantfile` I use a `chef_solo` provisioner with the following configuration:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.environments_path  = 'environments'
  chef.environment        = 'development'
  chef.run_list = [
    "recipe[service-ldap::default]"
  ]
end
```

I have the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin installed and the provisioning works, besides that I do not get any attributes that I have set in the `environments/development.rb`.

My question is, whether - and if yes, how - it is possible to use Chef Environments with Berkshelf or whether this is not part of the development workflow in Berkshelf. Maybe you could provide me a hint, how to achieve a workaround then.

Comment: Hi Mimi :-) As Berkshelf is run prior to the Chef run (for  dependency resolving) it does not care about environments at all. However, the Chef run itself triggered by Vagrant will respect environments. So I'm wondering, why your environment attributes are not included - a link to your code might help others.

Comment: The [environment cookbook pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/) to which you are referring proposes to use environment-specific cookbooks and to replace chef environments with a cookbook (version) shared across the whole environment (as cookbooks can be versioned). Not sure, if there is a  misunderstanding here in the way you think of that pattern. Wish I were sitting next to you.

Comment: mh hm - seems like I didn't get the concept of the Environment Cookbook Pattern. Working with the pattern I thought you only have "one" cookbook with which you set up a whole machine / application. The idea was to use the Chef Environments to tackle differences of this machine / application in development and production. Might be easier to talk about this sitting next to each other indeed :-)

Comment: If you are looking for having only one "top-level" cookbook that represents your application you might want to have a look at the [vagrant-toplevel-cookbooks plugin](https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-toplevel-cookbooks). It uses the `metadata.rb` / `Berksfile.lock` of the top-level cookbook for locking the dependency graph rather than environments. That means you can use environments for environments again (like dev / test / staging / prod) and you only need to specify the version of the top-level cookbook there (all transitive deps are defined in there).

Comment: @TorbenKnerr - thx for your answer. I think that my problem lies in a misunderstanding from my side concerning the Environment Cookbook Pattern. After reading it up again and trying to understand what's its purpose, I think that I don't need the Chef environments anymore, once I use it in a proper way.